# How to catch unhashed paths using hashed location strategy?

Tags: angular, server, hash-location-strategy

I've had troubles solving this. We're using **HashLocationStrategy** in our application and for some cases we will not be changing this. But I have to catch certain paths containing a series of numbers like this:

```
www.someurl.com/1241234
```

I have implemented a Angular directive to catch these by subscribing router events. It succeeds to catch when user types url with hashed location like this:

```
www.someurl.com/#/1241234
```

the subscription in directive catches *1241234* number correctly and I am able to apply my logic before redirecting to 404 not found page as intended (successfully). But **I have to** also catch the series when user types the url as `www.someurl.com/1241234` but this time application automatically redirects `www.someurl.com/#/notfoundpage`.

Is there a way to redirect `www.someurl.com/1241234` to `www.someurl.com/#/1241234` or handle path location strategy `www.someurl.com/1241234` somehow?

edit: number can change. So it may be like `www.someurl.com/6345`, `www.someurl.com/124`, `www.someurl.com/983` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best bet is to check the location and redirect before you bootstrap your angular application:

```js
... imports

//check if path is a number /1234
if (location.pathname.match(/^\/\d+$/)) {
  //add a hash in front of the pathname
  location.replace('/#' + location.pathname);
} 

//bootstrap angular
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch((err) => console.error(err));
```